# Adding inferred triples into an existing RDF file

Tags: owl, protege

I am currently using Protege and I was wondering whether it is actually possible to add the inferred triples (by using a reasoner) into an existing RDF file? After getting inferred triples, I would like to add them onto the existing file. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In the **File** menu, there's an item **Export inferred axioms as ontology**.  Exactly which inferred statements will be saved is customizable, and you'll be prompted after selecting that menu item.  For instance, when starting with this ontology:

```
@prefix :      <http://www.example.org/testExport#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<http://www.example.org/testExport>
        a       owl:Ontology .

:Superclass  a  owl:Class .

:Subclass  a             owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  :Superclass .

:a      a       owl:NamedIndividual , :Subclass .
```

I get this exported information:

```
@prefix :      <http://www.example.org/testExport#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<http://www.example.org/testExport2>
        a       owl:Ontology .

:Superclass  a            owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf   owl:Thing ;
        owl:disjointWith  owl:Nothing .   # inferred

:Subclass  a              owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf   :Superclass ;
        owl:disjointWith  owl:Nothing .   # inferred

:a      a       owl:Thing ,               # inferred
                :Subclass ,
                :Superclass ,             # inferred
                owl:NamedIndividual .
```